# setState doesn't update state variable - React Native hooks

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, webhooks

I'm using the state variable to keep track of my previous state.

The animation works (without index), but when I do

```
const [index, setIndex] = useState(0)

useEffect(() => {
        animation.addListener((scroll) => {
            setTimeout(function() {
                let position = Math.floor(scroll.value / cardWidth + 0.75);
                if (position >= restaurants.length - 1) position = restaurants.length - 1;
                if (position <= 0) position = 0;

                console.log("position: ", position, "index: ", index)

                if (index !== position) {
                    setIndex(position);
                    const { coordinate } = restaurants[position];
                    mapRef.current.animateCamera({
                        center: {
                            latitude: coordinate.latitude,
                            longitude: coordinate.longitude,
                        },
                         altitude: 2000, // zooms in when viewing specific location
                    }, {duration: 1000}) // not sure if duration is actually doing anything
                }
            }, 3000);
        });
        return function cleanUp(): void { animation.removeAllListeners(); }
    }, []);
```

The index never updates. I've tried checking the prevState inside the setState function and that updates, but if I print index outside of setIndex -- it doesn't update. How can I fix this?

Output from console

```
position:  1 index:  0
position:  1 index:  0
position:  1 index:  0
position:  0 index:  0
position:  0 index:  0
position:  0 index:  0
position:  1 index:  0
position:  1 index:  0
position:  1 index:  0
position:  2 index:  0
position:  2 index:  0
position:  2 index:  0
```

**EDIT**: Changed code to have `stores[position]` instead of `stores[index]` and added a clean-up to `UseEffect`

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should check the rules of hooks again

[Hooks of rules][1]
[1]: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Answer (score 0):

React's `setState` is asynchronous, so `index` value will change **after** this function execution is finished. So better option here will be to use `stores[position]` in current code.

Another note, React's `state` should be used for data that is used in rendering (eg. shown somewhere). It's perfectly fine to use just local variable if it's used only in the code you've posted.

One more thing to keep in mind: don't forget to remove listeners when they are no longer needed. For example when element is unmounted from the page. To do it with `useEffect` you'll need to return a function that will do it.

Comment: I have tried using stores[position], but index still never changes. So when position = 0 == index, it doesn't run through the actions. Good point on the `useEffect`, I did just add in a clean up function

Example of my output
```
position:  1 index:  0
position:  1 index:  0
position:  2 index:  0
```

So even though, the position has changed and I've stopped scrolling, it only stays at 0

Comment: for future readers, that's b/c of closure in JS: callback function is created when `index` is `0`, and this value isn't updated when new values are assigned to the `index`.
To make it work as expected we can use react references (React.useRef) instead of `useState`: `const indexRef = React.useRef(0); ...; indexRef.current = position; console.log(indexRef.current);`. Keep in mind it won't cause rerender of the component, like state does. So you may need both :-)